# Mine (indicating possession) with multiple items

Tags: grammar

Today I've been doing some tasks and I've found one interesting thing as for me. So I'll explain what I mean.

Look at these sentences:

> My friend is 19 years old.
>   So is mine.

where *mine* refers to my friend (another person).

And now I want you to look at this sentence:

> My friends are 19 years old.

Should the response be "*So are mine*" or "*So are mines*"?

I know there is a verb "to mine"(like to dig) I know but I'm really confused with it.

If I understand it well, "Mine"(NOT A VERB) works as for singular (A friend) and plural (friends).

Comment: ***Mine, yours, his*** etc. are "pronouns", for which the corresponding "possessive adjectives" are ***my, your, his***, etc. Note that ***his*** has the same form in both usages, so whereas it's *So is **mine*** = *So is **my** friend* and *So is **yours*** = *So is **your** friend*, the third person singular versions are *So is **his*** and *So is **his** friend*.

Comment: @Max, does it seem helpful, or not, that you chose to see things that way, please?

If you’re seriously asking: ‘Should the response be "So are mine" or "So are mines”?’ Then no; never either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form is as you predict:

> *My friends are all 19 years old.*
>
> *So are* ***mine***.

"Mine" is a possessive pronoun — it functions as the subject of the sentence, taking place of (in this case) "my friends." It does not change form based on any grammatical properties of the antecedent, including number, and so it takes the form "mine" regardless of whether the original subject was singular or plural. However, the verb which follows it *will* change based on the original subject:

> *My friend is 19 years old.*
>
> *So **is** mine.*